Why is the correct way of drafting this Intuit Developer API call?
I'm working with the Intuit Developer API to fetch data from within a QuickBooks Sandbox account and I am encountering an unexpected error, and I don't know why.
The direct purpose of the API call is to fetch a list of customers from within the pre-written Sandbox data.  The general purpose of the API call is so that invoices can be generated for one customer (the same customer) based on transactions completed within a smartphone application managed by that customer.
The response from the Intuit API is statusCode 401 which confirms a denial of authorisation, yet a fresh OAuth 2.0 access token is generated and supplied at the time of placing the API call.
My code for generating an OAuth 2.0 access token is as follows:


async function intuitAccess() {

        const tokenPATH = 'https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer';
        const header = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' };

        const params = {
            'client_id': process.env.INTUIT_CLIENT_ID,
            'client_secret': process.env.INTUIT_CLIENT_SECRET,
            'scope': process.env.INTUIT_SCOPES,
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
        };

        try {
            const tokenRequest = await correspond.post(tokenPATH).set(header).send(params);
            const responseData = tokenRequest.body;
            const token = responseData.access_token;
            console.log('Requested Token:', token);
            return token;
        } catch(error) {
            console.error('Error retrieving Intuit Access token:', error);
        }
    }



My code for requesting a list of customers is as follows:


async function intuitCustomerList() {
      try {
          const token = await intuitAccess();

          if (!token) {
              console.log('IntuitCustomerList: Access token is null.');
              return null;
          }

          // Delay for two seconds
          await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));

          const realmID = process.env.INTUIT_SANDBOX_REALM_ID;
          const query = 'SELECT * FROM Customer STARTPOSITION 1 MAXRESULTS 11';
          const PATH = `https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/${realmID}/query?query=${query}&minorversion=50`;
          const header = { "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + token, "Content-Type": "application/text" }; 

          const response = await correspond.get(PATH).set(header);

          if (!response) {
              console.error('Intuit API Error: Response is null');
              return null;
          }

              const responseData = response.text; 
              console.log('Intuit Selected Response:', responseData);
              return responseData;

      } catch(error) {
          console.error('Error Obtaining Intuit Customer List:', error);
          return null;
      }
  }



Console logs confirm:


statusCode: 401, 
statusMessage: 'Unauthorized',



The question I have is, since what I have written results in an authorisation error, what is the correct way of manually writing the API call in NodeJS so that the data is fetched/returned as desired please?
For HTTP calls, that is superagent.
With thanks.
